# Socket.io-auth - hide the credentials from payload request

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, authentication, encryption

Im building my socket application with laravel broadcaasting. I made my server script and then added https like in this script: (The code may contain errors because it is written from memory)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./file.crt')
};
var serverPort = 3000;

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

require('socketio-auth')(io, {
  authenticate: authenticate,
  postAuthenticate: postAuthenticate,
  disconnect: disconnect,
  timeout: 1000
});
```

after that i added socketio-auth and modified it for just username and password authentication.

```
function authenticate(socket, data, callback) {
    if (data.username != "username") {
      return callback(new Error("User not found"));
    }
    return callback(null, user.password == "password");
  }
}
```

My question is about credntials I'm sending via socket.

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';

Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('https://socketserver.com:1923', {secure: true}));

var vm = new Vue({
  sockets:{
    connect: function(){
      console.log('socket connected')
      this.$socket.emit('authentication', {username : "username", password: "password"});
    },
  },
})
```

Im actually using Vue with vue-socketio but its working with connection and with getting / sending information properly.

Problem  I got is when Im going to console in google chrome im getting plain text socket emit authentication information like 
(REQUEST PAYLOAD : {authentication: {username: "username", password : "password"}}).

Is that normal thing when Im using ssl? Something is wrong with my code? 
Or I need to encrypt then decrypt this information myself?

I thought all Im sending via HTTPS is encrypted.

Looking for ur replay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I made my own encryptor.
For client Im emiting encrypted information with data and the verify hash with socket.id.

And for server i decrypted and check hmac verification with socket.id.