# Trusted certificate not recognized when using socket.io in Electron main process

Tags: javascript, ssl, socket.io, electron, ssl-certificate

I have a server running Express and **socket.io 2.3.0** and an Electron app running socket.io-client 2.3.0 in the **main process**.
My server has **signed** (trusted) certificates.

From a browser or the renderer process the connection is working as expected. But from the main Electron's process I have to set `rejectUnauthorized: false` in the socket.io-client options for it to connect or I get a `TransportError` with code `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`.

The problem is that, when connected, **my queries to the server are not received**. I suspect the 'certificates' problem to be at the origin of this behavior.

**QUERIES EXAMPLE**

```
// This works: see UPDATE
socket.emit('db:[...PRIVATE...].count', (data: any) => {
  console.log(data)
})

// or

// Credentials are removed from the payload: see UPDATE
socket.emit('db:[...PRIVATE...].in', credentials, (data: any) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

throw this:

```
...
engine.io-client:socket flushing 1 packets in socket
engine.io-client:websocket websocket closed before onclose event
...
```

**CONFIGURATION**

*Server-side*:

```
SERVER = https.createServer({
  key: CONFIG.certificates.key,
  cert: CONFIG.certificates.cert
}, app);
// Listen to the HTTPS port
SERVER.listen(CONFIG.ports.https)
// Listen to the HTTP port
app.listen(CONFIG.ports.http, CONFIG.host)

const pingTimeout = 7000
const pingInterval = 3000
const io = SocketIO.listen(httpsServer, {
  pingTimeout,
  pingInterval
})
```

*Client-side* (Electron's main process):

```
SOCKET = io(`${process.env.[...PRIVATE...]!}`, { 
  reconnection: true,
  secure: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  // LINE BELOW: Tested with and without
  // transports: ["websocket"]
})
```

The Electron app is running on macOS 10.14.6 with **sandbox** and **contextIsolation** to true, **nodeIntegration** to false. In production mode, entitlements are including `com.apple.security.network.server`and `com.apple.security.network.client`

What could be the origin of the need to pass `rejectUnauthorized` option? Could this behavior be the result of a **security issue**?

### UPDATE

20210505

Actually the issue with the first example was only because of a typo.

But, I discovered that socket.io removes credentials if it detects an email in the payload, or even only the properties 'email' or 'password'. So, I guess that the issue remains: **how to make these certificates recognized by socket.io in order to be able to emit credentials to the server?**

Related:

- [Socket.io-auth - hide the credentials from payload request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47186523/1060921)

### UPDATE

20210507

Upgrading **from version 2.3.0 to version 4.0.2** resolved the problem of credentials 'auto-removal', but **didn't** resolve the need to pass `rejectUnauthorized: false` option.

- https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/
- https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/